# Cannot get Tomcat JDBCRealm to use SHA2

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, jdbcrealm, sha2

I am using Tomcat 7 / JDBCRealm authentication in clear text (development/controlled environment).  Now I want to upload the web app to my hosted environment so I need to digest the passwords.

I added 'digest="MD5"' to the realm section in server.xml and tested with some accounts by replacing the existing clear text password with one digested using MySQL's MD5() function.

This went OK.

When I tried SHA2 ('digest="SHA2"' in server.xml, and MySQL's SHA2() function to digest passwords in the table), I kept getting login failures.  I tried MySQL's SHA2(pwd,224), SHA2(pwd,256), ...384, ...515 and none worked.

My web search for tomcat JDBCRealm /digest property was not very informative.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Look in the Tomcat logs for the message that tells you SHA-2 is not a valid algorithm. If there is no such message, please raise a Tomcat bug.

You need to use one of the following:

- SHA-256
- SHA-384
- SHA-512

Obviously, you'll need to use the corresponding digest in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I do not recall seeing any error on tomcat logs, but I will double check in case I missed something.  Do I set digest="SHA-256" instead of digest="SHA2" in server.xml?  Where are the parameters for the JDBC realm documented ?  The standard html docs simply show the value for MD5 but not other digests. I googled it but came out empty-handed.

Comment: You need to use SHA-512 or one of the values I quoted above. The standard names for the supported MessageDigests are to be found in the Java documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest

Comment: Thanks Mark! I knew I was looking in the wrong place (tomcat documentation)